# Using a connection string where the password contains a "@" sign?

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, database

When connecting to a database server endpoint, using a connection string format such as the following:

```
mongodb://username:password@server:port/database
```

Is it possible to connect if the password contains an '@' sign?

If so, how?

Comment: did you try to url-encode the @?

Comment: Yes, tried using %40. Didn't work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the latest code from [Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/1.2.0) you can use:

```
new Mongo("mongodb://host/db", array("username" => $username, "password" => $password));
```